# Close toggle box by clicking anywhere else?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a simple open close toggle box, [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5jzUD/) and wondered if it could be closed by just clicking anywhere else on the site (as well as its current button) (not necessarily another link) whitespace, anywhere etc..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('a.show_hide').click(function() {
           $('.hidden-menu').toggle();
           $(this).toggleClass('close');
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/5jzUD/9/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click',function(clickPosition){
        if (!$('.hidden-menu, a.show_hide').is(clickPosition.target)    && $('.hidden-menu').has(clickPosition.target).length === 0){
            $('.hidden-menu').hide();
           $('a.show_hide').addClass('close');
            }
        else{
            if($('a.show_hide').is(clickPosition.target) && $('.hidden-menu').css('display')!='none'){
                $('.hidden-menu').hide();
               $('a.show_hide').addClass('close');
                return;
            }
            $('.hidden-menu').show();
           $('a.show_hide').removeClass('close');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jzUD/6/)

1. Use `$(document).click()` to bind or capture a click event - *anywhere else on the site*.
2. Use [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) in original `a` click event. This would stop event bubbling.
3. And, don't use `.toggle()` in the  `$(document).click()` function as it would also `show()` the element.

---

Check this snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.show_hide').click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('.hidden-menu').toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('close');
    });
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        $('.hidden-menu').hide();
        $('a.show_hide').removeClass('close');
    });
});
```

Instead of `$(document)` you could also use : `$('*:not(a.show_hide)')` : **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5jzUD/7/)**

Comment: this code hides the menu even if you click on it, so it's not what the OP wants!

Comment: I read this *wondered if it could be closed by just clicking anywhere else on the site*